# Is there a method of BreadCrumbBar I can overload to add an extra Component to be refreshed?

Tags: java, apache, wicket, wicket-7

I have a wicket page with a data panel that makes use of the `BreadCrumbBar` (org.apache.wicket.extensions.breadcrumb). If I go down a level a new breadcrumb is automatically added and the data panel is refreshed. If I click on one of the previous breadcrumbs my data panel gets updated correctly. Now I want to make sure some extra Component on the page (the title) also gets updated. This works fine when I control the link myself, but for the breadcrumb links I don't have full control.

Is there a method of `BreadCrumbBar` I can overload to add the extra Component to be refreshed? I assume the links in the `BreadCrumbBar` are ajax links, but I cannot find an ajax target in the `BreadCrumbBar` (or any of the child components).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `BreadCrumbBar` uses `BreadCrumbLink`s to render its links, which are usual `Link`s (and not `AjaxLink`s).

To get an ajax behavior, you could try to create your own link (`BreadCrumbAjaxLink`) implementation using `AjaxLink` as a base and implement in `onClick(AjaxRequestTarget)` the same logic that exists in `BreadCrumbLink`'s `onClick()`.

Then create an analogue of `BreadCrumbComponent` (let's call it `AjaxBreadCrumbComponent`) using your `BreadCrumbAjaxLink` instead of `BreadCrumbLink`.

And then override `BreadCrumbBar`'s `newBreadCrumbComponent()` method:

```
protected Component newBreadCrumbComponent(final String id, final long index, final int total,
    final IBreadCrumbParticipant breadCrumbParticipant)
{
    boolean enableLink = getEnableLinkToCurrent() || (index < (total - 1));
    return new AjaxBreadCrumbComponent(id, getSeparatorMarkup(), index, this,
        breadCrumbParticipant, enableLink);
}
```

In `BreadCrumbAjaxLink`, you could update whatever additional component you want. (You would probably need to update the bar itself too).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had considered doing this but it seemed a bit much for updating the page title only. This gives you the ability to change anything at any time, so it is more flexible. If necessary I can remove my tinkering and use this :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since extending several classes seemed a bit overkill for my use case, I tried something different that eventually worked.

By overloading the `setActive` method of the `BreadCrumbBar` I could set some text to the page title model. That text was then shown on the page.

I am still not sure how the `BreadCrumbBar` handles this. I think the entire page is refreshed and no ajax call is done.